# SQL to dynamically drop MySQL column constraint to prevent column update

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, relational-database

If I have a column constraint number on a table such as:

```
  `StartPollDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Where I want to remove the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` element of the constraint at runtime, to prevent the `StartPollDateTime` being updated with the current time and date when a change is made to a given row in the table, what might the SQL to remove this constraint be?

The issue here is that there a significant number of tables with a column of this nature and removing them manually is not viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change column definitions with `ALTER TABLE`

```
alter table one modify `StartPollDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```